# Clojure nested map - change value

Tags: dictionary, clojure, key

have to say I started learning Clojure about two weeks ago and now I'm stuck on a problem since three full days.

I got a map like this:

```
{
  :agent1 {:name "Doe" :firstname "John" :state "a" :time "VZ" :team "X"}
  :agent2 {:name "Don" :firstname "Silver" :state "a" :time "VZ" :team "X"}
  :agent3 {:name "Kim" :firstname "Test" :state "B" :time "ZZ" :team "G"}
}
```

and need to change `:team "X"` to `:team "H"`.
I tried with a lot of stuff like `assoc`, `update-in` etc. but nothing works.

How can I do my stuff?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

assoc-in is used for replacing or inserting values in the map specified by path

```
(def m { :agent1 {:name "Doe" :firstname "John" :state "a" :time "VZ" :team "X"}
         :agent2 {:name "Don" :firstname "Silver" :state "a" :time "VZ" :team "X"}
         :agent3 {:name "Kim" :firstname "Test" :state "B" :time "ZZ" :team "G"}})

(assoc-in m [:agent1 :team] "H")

{:agent1 {:state "a", :team "H", :name "Doe", :firstname "John", :time "VZ"},
 :agent2 {:state "a", :team "X", :name "Don", :firstname "Silver", :time "VZ"},
 :agent3 {:state "B", :team "G", :name "Kim", :firstname "Test", :time "ZZ"}}
```

however, if you want to update ALL team "X"'s, regardless of specific path, over all recursive levels of the tree, you can use clojure.walk's prewalk or postwalk functions combined with a function of your own:

```
(use 'clojure.walk)
(defn postwalk-mapentry
    [smap nmap form]
    (postwalk (fn [x] (if (= smap x) nmap x)) form))

(postwalk-mapentry [:team "X"] [:team "T"] m)

{:agent1 {:state "a", :team "T", :name "Doe", :firstname "John", :time "VZ"},
 :agent2 {:state "a", :team "T", :name "Don", :firstname "Silver", :time "VZ"},
 :agent3 {:state "B", :team "G", :name "Kim", :firstname "Test", :time "ZZ"}}
```

Answer (score 12):

The walking functions are good for replacement like that.

`(clojure.walk/prewalk-replace {[:team "X"] [:team "H"]} map)`

Passing in vectors allows you to ensure that you don't just replace all the "X"s.

Comment: Cool, didn't know that you could change a key-val combo with post- & prewalk-replace as well ! Thought it only worked on keys.

Comment: It works on entire structures - and a map key-value pair is mostly equivalent to a [key value] vector (think about using `(into {} (map (fn [[k v]] [k (inc v)]) {:a 1 :b 2})))` for example.  If something is equivalent, it'll substitute it - no matter how big it is.  Also remember you can use any Clojure data structure as a key in a map safely, which can be pretty powerful.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer! 
Unfortunately, I learned that I can only use functions from the core, because we can not ensure that the program, in which this code is integrated, supports more than the core functions with its next release. 
Is there also a way for this problem?

Comment: How can you not ensure that?  It's part of the main clojure library, and I don't see namespaces just going away from it.  `clojure.walk` covers the simplest way to handle this type of case, and before I found it I was writing equivalent code to it.  If there is a concern for it not being available, when that concern is realized I would just use the strategy used there for doing the tree walk - the main structure for maps for you would be like `(fn [f] (into {} (map (fn [[k v]] (if-let [result (transform k v)] result [k (f v)])` (note that's untested)